# Getting specific value from textfile not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, zpl

I have a zpllabel.txt file that I read into memory but I want to get all the ^FO values from the textfile and add to it the value that user enters to offset the printer.

```
^XA^MCY^PRD,D,D^MMT,N^XZ                                                
^XA                                                           
^DFCASENEW^FS                                                 
^LH0,0                                                        
^FO33,45^A0N,90,98^FN01^FS^FX Company^FS                      
^FO879,28^A0N,263,214^FN02^FS^FX Product^FS                   
^FO30,159^A0N,90,58^FN03^FS^FX Description^FS                 
^FO42,321^A0N,65,68^FN04^FS^FX NumberIn^FS                    
^FO100,436^A0N,75,66^FN05^FS^FX SelectCode^FS                 
^BY6,,230^FO260,252^BCN,,N,N,N,N^FN06^FS^FX RotationProduct^FS
^FO660,503^A0N,32,98^FN07^FS^FX RotationProduct^FS            
^BY4,3.0,204^FO60,518^B2N,,N,N,N^FN08^FS^FX UPCCode^FS        
^FO170,732^A0N,24,47^FN09^FS^FX UPCCode^FS                    
^FO32,516^GB590,0,10^FS                                       
^FO32,717^GB590,0,10^FS                                       
^FO640,573^A0N,226,212^FN10^FS^FX Rotation^FS                 
^FO1362,546^A0N,90,66^FDBest Before^FS                        
^FO1235,628^A0N,134,140^FN11^FS^FX BestBefore^FS              
^FO55,391^A0N,43,77^FDSEL^FS                                  
^FO30,267^A0N,54,100^FDQTY^FS                                 
^XZ                                                           
^XA^XFCASENEW
^FN01^FDCompany^FS
^FN02^FDProduct^FS
^FN03^FDDescription^FS
^FN04^FDNumberIn^FS
^FN05^FDSelectCode^FS
^FN06^FDRotationProduct^FS
^FN07^FD^FS
^FN08^FDUPCCode^FS
^FN09^FD^FS
^FN10^FDRotation^FS
^FN11^FDBestBefore^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
^XA^ID*.*^XZ
```

so for example 5th line of the label needs to be FO43 if the user enters an offset value of 10 and needs to be 23 if he enters  -10 as the offset value, I am a noob at handling textfiles in c# please help

I have this code that replaces a pair of text:

```
 try
{
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\something\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\zplTest\\zplTest\\zpllabel3.txt");
 using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(file))
  {
  using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(memory))
   {
  string input = reader.ReadToEnd();
     // for (int i = 0; 1 < file.Length; i++)
   {
  using (MemoryStream writermemory = new MemoryStream())
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writermemory))
    {
   Dictionary<string, string> replacementcollections =
   new Dictionary<string, string>();
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN01^FDCompany^FS", compname);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN02^FDProduct^FS", stlabel23);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN03^FDDescription^FS", stlabel24);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN04^FDNumberIn^FS", stlabel25);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN05^FDSelectCode^FS", stlabel26);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN06^FDRotationProduct^FS", stlabel27);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN07^FD^FS", stlabel28);
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN08^FDUPCCode^FS", stlabel29.TrimEnd());
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN09^FD^FS", stlabel30.TrimEnd());
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN10^FDRotation^FS", "^FN10^FD" + TxtRotcode.Text.Trim() + "^FS");
   replacementcollections.Add
   ("^FN11^FDBestBefore^FS", "^FN11^FD" + TxtBestBefore.Text.Trim() + "^FS");
    replacementcollections.Add
   ("^PQ1,0,1,Y", "PQ" + TxtQty.Text.Trim() + ",0,1,Y");
   string output = input;
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> 
   replacement in replacementcollections)
   { output = output.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value); }
   Label256.Visible = true;
   zplcode.Text = output;
   zplcode.Visible = true;
    writer.Close();
    ZplPreview();
  }

}
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
  }
```

so what I would like to accomplish 
1) read text file into memory
2) find all the values of "FO"
3) add or subtract that value with what the user enters
4) send it to the textbox
5) I later send that text to the zebra printer

I tried:

```
 using 
(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(memory)) 
{ 
int offset = Convert.ToInt32(txtOffSet.Text); 
string inputs = reader.ReadToEnd();
Regex r = new Regex("\\^FO([0-9]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline); 
string res = r.Replace(Convert.ToString(reader), (input) => "^FO" + (int.Parse(input.Groups[1].Value) + offset).ToString());
 // for (int i = 0; 1 < file.Length; i++) 
{
```

Comment: @Gusman I tried your solution but the FO values are still the same, but you understood my requirement correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your question is really vague and your code has nothing to do with what you asked, but this can help you on the replacement you requested.

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("path/to/your/file");

int offset = 10; //Store here your offset, positive to add it, negative to subtract it

Regex r = new Regex("\\^FO([0-9]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string res = r.Replace(fileContent, (input) => "^FO" + (int.Parse(input.Groups[1].Value) + offset).ToString());

//Now you have the content of the file with the FO replaced with it's new values
Debug.Write(res);
```

Comment: I tried this but the FO values are still same, please help:       using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(memory))
  {
int offset = Convert.ToInt32(txtOffSet.Text);
string inputs = reader.ReadToEnd();
 Regex r = new Regex("\\^FO([0-9]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string res = r.Replace(Convert.ToString(reader), (input) => "^FO" + (int.Parse(input.Groups[1].Value) + offset).ToString());
// for (int i = 0; 1 < file.Length; i++)
{